How to change ORM to Postgresql Insert query to bulk insert in odoo 12 enterprise
I have a problem when inserting data with Odoo. I use Odoo 12 enterprise. When I call below function, the code execution is over 40 seconds, but my target is under 20 seconds,
This is my code:
` @api.multi
    def action_confirm_1(self):
        # start_time = time.monotonic()
        request_plan = self.filtered(lambda r: r.state == 'checked')
        if not request_plan:
            return False
        for plan in request_plan:
            Production = self.env['mrp.production']
            ProductionSudo = Production.sudo(self.env.user).with_context(force_company=plan.company_id.id)
            for line in plan.plan_line_ids:
                vals = line._prepare_production_vals(picking_type_id=plan.picking_type_id)
                production = ProductionSudo.create(vals)
                if production.child_production_ids:
                    child_production = plan.get_child_production_ids(production)
                    if child_production:
                        child_production.write({'plan_order_id': plan.id})
        request_plan.write({'state': 'confirm'})
        return True`

Result From Variable Vars is
`
{'origin': False, 
'product_id': 47322, 
'product_qty': 1000.0, 
'product_uom_id': 8, 
'location_src_id': 54, 
'location_dest_id': 54, 'bom_id': 46430, 
'date_planned_start': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2), 
'date_planned_finished': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2), 
'procurement_group_id': False,
 'propagate': False, 
 'picking_type_id': 32, 
 'company_id': 4, 
 'user_id': 146, 
 'plan_order_id': 6515}`

This is _prepare_production_vals code:
`@api.multi
    def _prepare_production_vals(self, picking_type_id):
        self.ensure_one()
        company_id = self.plan_id.company_id or self.env.user.company_id
        if picking_type_id.default_location_src_id:
            location_id = picking_type_id.default_location_src_id.id
        else:
            location_id = self._get_vals_location_id(
                company_id=company_id)
        if picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id:
            location_dest_id = picking_type_id.default_location_dest_id.id
        else:
            location_dest_id = self._get_vals_location_id(
                company_id=company_id)
        return {
            'origin': self.origin,
            'product_id': self.product_id.id,
            'product_qty': self.product_qty,
            'product_uom_id': self.product_uom_id.id,
            'location_src_id': location_id,
            'location_dest_id': location_dest_id,
            'bom_id': self.bom_id.id,
            'date_planned_start': self.schedule_date or fields.Datetime.now,
            'date_planned_finished': self.schedule_date or fields.Datetime.now,
            'procurement_group_id': False,
            'propagate': False,
            'picking_type_id': picking_type_id.id or self.with_context(
                company_id=company_id)._get_vals_picking_type(),
            'company_id': company_id.id,
            'user_id': self.plan_id.user_id and self.plan_id.user_id.id or \
                self.env.user.id,
            'plan_order_id': self.plan_id.id
        }`

This is get_child_production_ids code:
` def get_child_production_ids(self, production):
        child_production = self.env['mrp.production']
        queue = [(production, False)]  # (production, visited)
        while queue:
            current_production, visited = queue.pop(0)
            if not visited:
                child_production |= current_production
                queue.extend((child, False) for child in current_production.child_production_ids)
                queue.append((current_production, True))
        return child_production

How to change production = ProductionSudo.create(vals) , to SQL query or stored procedure in postgresql?
I expect to boost performance insert data to postgresql ...

What about a multi create for all productions of one plan and also a multi write on all child productions of that earlier created productions?

its create child of manufacture order per process

Do you have some numbers? How many productions (without childs) are create in one call? And how many child productions are created and have to be written in one call?

i need to change  production = ProductionSudo.create(vals) to SQL query in odoo , do you have example code ?

No, because i won't do that. I'm trying to solve it by an alternative, but if you want to do it by an sql query, you have to wait for another one answering your question.

please give me your code for solution
